# Prove that $\frac{1}{x^3+2}+\frac{1}{y^3+2}+\frac{1}{z^3+2}\leq 1$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

*question*

Let $x,y,z$ be positive numbers such that $xyz\geq 1$. Prove that $\frac{1}{x^3+2}+\frac{1}{y^3+2}+\frac{1}{z^3+2}\leq 1$.

*my idea*

if we look closely we realise that we have to prove that

$\frac{1}{x^3+2}+\frac{1}{y^3+2}+\frac{1}{z^3+2}\leq xyz$

The first thing I thought of is the inequlity of means or CBS

A thing i demonstrated by Am-Gm is

$x^3+2=3x$

I think thismight help us. I dont know what to do forward. Hope one of you can help me! Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x=ka,$ $y=kb$ and $z=kc,$ where $k>0$ and $abc=1$.

Thus, $$k^3abc\geq abc,$$which gives $k\geq1$ and
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{x^3+2}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{k^3a^3+2}\leq\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{a^3+2}$$and it's enough to prove that $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{a^3+2}\leq1$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{a^3+2abc}\leq\frac{1}{abc}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{bc}{a^2+2bc}\leq1,$$ which is true by C-S:
$$1-\sum_{cyc}\frac{bc}{a^2+2bc}=-\frac{1}{2}-\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{bc}{a^2+2bc}-\frac{1}{2}\right)=$$
$$=-\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{2(a^2+2bc)}\geq-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{2\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2+2bc)}=0.$$
I used C-S in the Engel's form:

> Let $a_i$ real numbers and $b_i>0$.
> Prove that:
> $$\frac{a_1^2}{b_1}+\frac{a_2^2}{b_2}+...+\frac{a_n^2}{b_n}\geq\frac{(a_1+a_2+...+a_n)^2}{b_1+b_2+...+b_n}.$$

Comment: How did you went from having to prove $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{a^3+2}\leq1$$ to having to prove
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{a^3+2abc}\leq\frac{1}{abc}$$? Thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: @Ionela Buciu Because $abc=1$. See my solution.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg may i ask you one qurstion? I know the CBS formula and i wonder wchich term is which. Like which one is $a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3$. Thank you!

Comment: @Matei Trandafir I am not sure that I understood your question. Do you want that I'll explain, how I used C-S?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg yes, thats right. Can you please explain me how you used it? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$\sqrt[3]{(x^3+2)(y^3+2)(z^3+2)}=:G$

By GM-HM,

$$\frac{3}{\frac{1}{x^3+2}+\frac{1}{y^3+2}+\frac{1}{z^3+2}}\le \sqrt[3]{(x^3+2)(y^3+2)(z^3+2)}\\\Rightarrow \frac{1}{3}({\frac{1}{x^3+2}+\frac{1}{y^3+2}+\frac{1}{z^3+2}})\ge\frac{1}{G}$$

Now, $G^3{=(x^3+2)(y^3+2)(z^3+2)\\=x^3 y^3 z^3 + 2 x^3 y^3 + 2 x^3 z^3 + 4 x^3 + 2 y^3 z^3 + 4 y^3 + 4 z^3 + 8\\=9+2\underbrace{(x^3 y^3 + x^3 z^3 + y^3 z^3)}_{\text{$\ge 3\sqrt[3]{x^6y^6z^6}=3$ }}+4\underbrace{(x^3+y^3+z^3)}_{\text{$\ge 3\sqrt[3]{x^3y^3z^3}=3$ }}}$

Now, by AM-GM we can show, $G^3\ge9+2 \times 3+4\times3=27\quad(\because xyz=1)\\\Rightarrow \frac{1}{G}\le\frac {1}{3}$

$$\therefore\frac{1}{3}({\frac{1}{x^3+2}+\frac{1}{y^3+2}+\frac{1}{z^3+2}})\le\frac{1}{3}\Rightarrow  \frac{1}{x^3+2}+\frac{1}{y^3+2}+\frac{1}{z^3+2}\leq 1$$

Comment: I think, the step $\therefore \frac{3}{\frac{1}{x^3+2}+\frac{1}{y^3+2}+\frac{1}{z^3+2}}\ge3$ is wrong.

Comment: -1 I concur with Michael   $\quad$ As an aside, faster to show that $ \prod (x^3 + 1 + 1 ) \geq \prod 3x \geq 27$.

Comment: @O M you used the following. If $A\geq B$ and $B\leq C$ so $A\leq C$. I think, it's wrong.

Comment: @O M It's an unique error. Just all your solution is wrong.

Comment: But the proof is mine. We say about your proof. Your proof is wrong, I think

Answer (score 1):

The given inequality is equivalent to:

$$(y^3+2)(z^3+2)+(x^3+2)(z^3+2)+(x^3+2)(y^3+2) \leq (x^3+2)(y^3+2)(z^3+2)$$
$$y^3z^3 + 2y^3 + 2z^3 + 4 + x^3z^3 + 2x^3 + 2z^3 + 4 + x^3y^3 + 2x^3 + 2y^3 + 4 \leq x^3y^3z^3+2x^3y^3 + 2x^3z^3+4x^3 + 2y^3z^3+4y^3 + 4z^3 + 8$$
$$x^3z^3 + x^3y^3 + y^3z^3 + 4x^3 + 4y^3 + 4z^3 + 12 \leq x^3y^3z^3 + 2x^3y^3 + 2x^3z^3 + 2y^3z^3 + 4x^3 + 4y^3 + 4z^3 + 8$$
$$4 \leq x^3y^3z^3 + x^3y^3 + x^3z^3 + y^3z^3$$

For simplicity, let $u = x^3$, $v = y^3$, and $w = z^3$.  Then:

$$4 \leq uvw + uv + uw + vw$$

Now, let $A = \frac{u + v + w}{3}$, $G = \sqrt[3]{uvw}$, and $H = \frac{3uvw}{uv + uw + vw}$ be the arithmetic, geometric, and harmonic means of the three cubed values.  Then:

$$4 \leq G^3 + \frac{3G^3}{H}$$

Since all the steps I've used are reversible (except when any of $u$, $v$, or $w$ are $-2$, but that's ruled out by the positivity assumption), if we can prove this inequality, it proves the original expression.

Now, we are given that $xyz = \sqrt[3]{uvw} = G \ge 1$, and thus $G^2 \ge 1$ and $G^3 \ge 1$.

Also, by the HM-GM inequality, $H \le G$.  So $\frac{1}{H} \ge \frac{1}{G}$, and

$$\frac{3G^3}{H} \ge 3G^2 \ge 3$$

Since $G^3 \ge 1$ and $\frac{3G^3}{H} \ge 3$, we have $G^3 + \frac{3G^3}{H} \ge 4$, QED.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{1}{x^3+2}+\frac{1}{y^3+2}+\frac{1}{z^3+2}\leq 1\Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{x^3+2}+\frac{1}{y^3+2}+\frac{1}{z^3+2}-1\le0$$

Now, $$\frac{1}{x^3+2}+\frac{1}{y^3+2}+\frac{1}{z^3+2}-1\\=-\frac{x^2 y^2 z^2 + x^2 y^2 + x^2 z^2 + y^2 z^2 - 4}{(x^2 + 2) (y^2 + 2) (z^2 + 2)}$$

So, $x^2 y^2 z^2 + x^2 y^2 + x^2 z^2 + y^2 z^2 - 4\ge0$ is enough to prove the inequility.

By AM-GM, $$x^2 y^2 z^2 + \underbrace{x^2 y^2 + x^2 z^2 + y^2 z^2}_{\ge \sqrt[3]{x^4y^4z^4}} - 4\ge1+3-4=0\quad(\because xyz=1)\quad\square$$